# Using for loops and if statements in LESS

Tags: less

I have written out what I am trying to achieve in PHP which is as follows:

```
for($i=1; $i<13; $i++) {
    for($a=1; $a<13; $a++) {
        if(($a + $i) > 12) {
            echo ".col-xs-".$i." + .col-xs-".$a." { margin-top: 10px; }".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
.col-xs-1 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-2 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-2 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-3 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-3 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-3 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-4 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-4 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-4 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-4 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-5 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-5 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-5 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-5 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-5 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-6 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-7 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-5 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-8 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-4 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-5 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-9 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-3 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-4 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-5 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-10 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-3 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-4 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-5 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-11 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-1 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-3 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-4 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-5 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-6 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-7 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-8 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-9 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-10 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-11 { margin-top: 10px; }
.col-xs-12 + .col-xs-12 { margin-top: 10px; }
```

Instead of copying and pasting this output into my less file I would rather get less to do the same logic instead so that it is cleaner but what I have isn't working. Here is my code:

```
.generate-columns(13);

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

    .generate-columns2(@m, @l: 1) when (@l =< @m) {
        when (@i + @l > 12) {
            .col-xs-@{i} + .col-xs-@{l} {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        }

        .generate-columns2(@m, (@l + 1));
    }

    .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```

The error I'm getting is when trying to compile the less is:

```
>> ParseError: Unrecognised input in assets\less\utility.less on line 77, column 33:
>> 76         .generate-columns2(@m, @l: 1) when (@l =< @m) {
>> 77             when (@i + @l > 12) {
>> 78                 .col-xs-@{i} + .col-xs-@{l} {
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: You are missing an `&` before `when (@i + @l > 12) {` (and you are not calling the inner mixin anywhere).

Comment: It's more optimal to use `when` directly with `.col-xs-@{i} + .col-xs-@{l}` selector. There's no point in separate `& {}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry) I was missing an `&` before `when` and wasn't calling the inner mixin anywhere. The solution is:

```
.generate-columns(13);

.generate-columns(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {

    .generate-columns2(13);

    .generate-columns2(@m, @l: 1) when (@l =< @m) {
        &when (@i + @l > 12) {
            .col-xs-@{i} + .col-xs-@{l} {
                margin-top: 10px;
            }
        }

        .generate-columns2(@m, (@l + 1));
    }

    .generate-columns(@n, (@i + 1));
}
```